# Firebase moving between lists with transactions

Tags: transactions, firebase

I want to have multiple large lists (essentially queues of tasks) stored in Firebase and have a client process monitoring them. Ideally, I'd want to be able to use a transaction to move tasks between the lists. The easy first approach was to keep separate lists of tasks and run a transaction on a common ancestor node.

**Q1**. Does this transaction end up fetching all of the data under the common ancestor every time the transaction is run?

If so, my first approach seems wasteful if the lists are large and we have to do the transaction repeatedly. My next idea was to hold multiple lists under a single node, but have the priorities act as tags for which list they belong in. Thus you can query for a specific priority tag, and move tasks between lists by just changing the priority.

**Q2**. Are there any big downsides to tagging lists like this? Is it good practice?

Comment: Q1) some of it may depend on your code (and the API you use to access Firebase), but in general the answer is "no, Firebase will only retrieve the data once and then update it when it changes".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Nice. I'm expecting the lists to update outside of this client process, so I guess the first approach will be pretty efficient if the lists' changes over time are slow compared to the rate of my transactions.

Comment: I once did a "shared task queue" system like that over Firebase, but quickly saturated the pipes. The tasks were too small, so there was just too much communication going on. I switched over to a pick-a-random-task system then, which meant each client would only consider one/a few tasks a a time. That worked pretty well, especially given its simplicity. But there are many other ways to consider for task distribution, each with their own merits and problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old, but still:

Q1: If you are referring to Firebase.transaction(), then yes, it'll fetch all the data. Don't do this.

Q2: It may be a good idea, but remember:

1) if you use .orderByX, (to filter by tag), you cannot use .orderByX second time. In other words, you can query for 'priority=done' or you can 'order_by_date' but currently you cannot combine both of these.

2) you won't be able to write custom validation rules for some filtered part of the single node.

Better solutions:

1) check out multi-location updates: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html

2) check out firebase-transactions project: https://github.com/vacuumlabs/firebase-transactions (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors)